# resetting timeout on each document click with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout

I am struggling in getting a `timeout` timer to reset with each `document` `click` interaction. The `clearTimeout` does not seem to be working.

jquery:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
  $("#vidBack").hide();
  $(".mainer").show();

  function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  var timer =  setTimeout(function(){
        $(".bury").hide();
        $(".mainer").hide();
        $("#meetSub").hide();
        $("#leaguesSub").hide();
        $("#memberSub").hide();
        $(".bury").hide();
        $("#welcomeSub").show();
        $("#vidBack").show();
        $("#vida").prop("volume", 0);       
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: when you are calling stop timer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactor your code to something like this:

```js
var timer;

function resetTimer() {
  if(timer)
    clearTimeout(timer);
  
  $("#vidBack").hide();
  $(".mainer").show();
  
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".mainer").hide();
    $("#vidBack").show();
  },  5000);
  
}

$(document).click(resetTimer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainer">mainer</div>
<div id="vidBack">vidBack</div>
```